# Error in Heroku-apps

Tags: heroku

I'm able to deploy to Heroku, but can't add keys.

When I enter "Heroku keys" or "Heroku keys:add", I get the following message:

Error in heroku-apps:
Cannot find module 'is-stream'

Any ideas of how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you tell me which OS you are using and which version of the Heroku Toolbelt you are using?

Comment: I'm using Cloud9, actually, and Heroku's free version. Not sure if this info helps.

Comment: what does `heroku --version` return?

Comment: Try updating your heroku-cli... https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/226